# Subtract two arrays, keep only values where the other has no data

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I've been trying to subtract (and combine an multiply etc.) two Numpy arrays so that the resulting array would have values left only in such places, where the other array has no data.

Like if I have matrices a and b, a-b would give c:

```
a = np.array([0,2,3,0])
b = np.array([1,0,3,0])
c = np.array([0,2,0,0])
```

I've already tried multiplying b with a very big number, but then I couldn't figure out how to get rid of the negative values. There is also that that the arrays a and b have missing values as -999.

Help would be very appreciated!Thanks!

Comment: where the other array has no data - what other array? a,b, both?

Comment: If b has a value !=0 somewhere, I need to create a new array from a (->c), such that it has 0 in the same place as b has value !=0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this?

```
>>> a = np.array([0,2,3,0])
>>> b = np.array([1,0,3,0])
>>> a[b!=0] = 0
>>> a
array([0, 2, 0, 0])
```

Comment: This seems to work, thanks! Although I get "AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'shape'" for my script but that probably has something to do with matplotlib and pcolormesh etc. then. Should I mark this as answered?

Comment: This is another problem and not connected to this one. You seem to do `m.shape`, where `m` is an integer, not an `ndarray`.

Comment: Yeah, I know it is another problem, thank you @AshwiniChaudhary for a fast and working solution! I just couldn't mark it as answered with my phone so I thought I lacked enough reputation or something. It's sometimes sad one needs enough reputation to up vote a good answer.